# What is the point of Spring Boot starter cache dependency?

Tags: java, spring, caching

It seems like it has some basic dependencies and all caching works without it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html

> Use the spring-boot-starter-cache “Starter” to quickly add basic
> caching dependencies. The starter brings in spring-context-support. If
> you add dependencies manually, you must include spring-context-support
> in order to use the JCache, EhCache 2.x, or Caffeine support.

So, likely spring-context-support is already included from other Spring imports, but in the case you ONLY imported spring-boot-starter-cache it would include what you need.